# Kentico report - reference field A value from dependent field B

Tags: field, reporting, kentico

I am creating a report (in Kentico 10) which has 'cascading' parameters.  In order to describe my problem, it is sufficient to mention the following report parameters:

1. Region (North America, Asia Pacific, etc.) - a dropdown driven by a SQL query
2. Country (US, CA, MX, DE, FR, etc.) - a dropdown driven by a SQL query, limited by the value of the Region field

When viewing the report, I would like for the value chosen in the Region field to affect the contents of the Country field.  The SQL code is not a problem, but actually getting the value of the Country field is.

I have configured the Region field with 'Has depending fields' checked.
I have configured the Country field with 'Depends on another field' checked. In the WHERE clause of its SQL query, I reference `'{%Region.Value%}'`.  (per [this](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-work-with-depending-fields) article) This does not work.  Upon further investigation, I found that the result of `{%Region.Value%}` is "RegionName", which is the field name specified in the Region field's 'Value column' setting.

How do I access the *selected value* in the Region dropdown, rather than the *name of the field* whose value is displayed in that dropdown?

A subsequent question would be: After choosing a Region, the page posts back and my Region choice is lost.  How do I make it stick?

(Also, it is not acceptable to replace the SQL-driven dropdown with a static list of regions.  This needs to be SQL driven, as there are other dependent fields whose possible values are not static.)

Answer (score 1):

Only the value part is passed to your depending field, so if your region SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT RegionID, RegionName from Custom_Region
```

The RegionID is the value of the {%Region.Value%} macro.
If you need to pass the region Name the query would look like this:

```
SELECT RegionName, RegionName from Custom_Region
```

Comment: I may not have been clear enough but my point was that {%Region.Value%} is returning the field *name* and not the value that the user has selected.

Comment: That doesn't make sense :-/ What version and hotfix do you have? I have tested it and I am getting correct value.

Comment: OK, my mistake was simple.  In the first (region) parameter, I'd specified the value column to be 'Name'.  I should have set it to '{%Name%}'.